# JavaScript onClick: I have to click twice for modal to appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, onclick

I am trying to add a click event to a button element with a dynamically changing id. However to actually get the popup to appear, I have to click the button twice... I know it is happening like this, because I am doing something wrong with click event. But I can't figure out how to solve the issue. 
Can you? I am pulling my hair out over this...

Thanks so much in advance

```js
// Get the modal
function getPopup(venue_id){
 var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
 var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn"+venue_id);
 var venue = document.getElementById("title"+venue_id).innerHTML;
 document.getElementById("eventTitle").innerHTML = "<h3>"+venue+"</h3>";
 var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];



 btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
 }
 span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
 }
 window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
   modal.style.display = "none";
  }
 }
}


function sentPopup(){
 document.getElementById('myModal').style.display ="none";
 var modal = document.getElementById('thanksMessage');
 var span = document.getElementById("close");
 modal.style.display = "block";
 span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
 }
 window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
   modal.style.display = "none";
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<?php /* $venue_id is being populated by a php function which doesnt matter for this click issue to solve */
<button class="btn" id="myBtn'.$venue_id.'" onclick="getPopup('.$venue_id.')">Unverbindlich anfragen</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <span class="close">x</span>
  <p class="venuePopupTitle" id="eventTitle"></p>
  <form>my form</form>
 </div>
</div>
?>
```

Comment: remove window.onclick from getPopup() and check !
This window.onclick is making the modal display to none for the 1st time. Hence you need to click the button again.

Comment: Please post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is the button inside your modal? Could you post a snippet of your html as well?

Comment: edited my question

Comment: @Pat I tested to remove the window.onclick from getPopup() but it didnt help.

Comment: @klikas Nope, it is not inside the modal.. it is the trigger in the page to actually open the modal ;)

Comment: @Saskia, could you try return false; in the end of your button.onclick function?
This way we can at least establish that it is not an event bubbling issue.

Comment: @klikas thanks for trying to help! but adding return false; to btn.onclick function after modal.style.display = "block"; didnt do anything. I still have to click the button twice initially to get the modal to appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saskia, the reason you need to click twice, is that this:

```
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

Is inside the getPopUp function, which only gets called when you click the button. So when you click once, only then, it sets the onclick function to button.

You need to change this lines to perform the action immediately, so inside getPopUp, you need to do:

```
modal.style.display = "block";
```

Without the btn.onclick.

The same for the other button inside sentPopUp because you will have the same issues.

I would recommend you get rid of inline onclick attributes in your HTML and use unobtrusive style of writing javascript to avoid errors.

Comment: thanks @klikas ! I knew it had to do with the event being called inside the function.. but I couldnt see the mistake somehow! Thank you very much again!